# Codeingiter - RESTful API Key auth for only certain Routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, rest

I'm in the process of building a RESTful API server. Everything is working as it should be as of now.

I'm using Phil Sturgeon RESTful server implementation for CodeIgniter which is pretty much popular.
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

What i need is to have a Basic API key authentication for some of the routes which this Package already provides, but it does apply to all the API Routes.

I do not want Authentication for all Routes..as some API should be called without Authentication
How do we achieve it..

**Note :** I cant switch the technology or framework as I'm currently using the Models which have been developed before and being used now.

Eg Route without Auth  : `$route['api/products'] = "api/Products/allProducts";`

Eg Route with Auth : `$route['api/devices/update'] = "api/Devices/updateDevice";`

Comment: You should define your own AUTH as a library and use this in the Controller. Your library will decide which API call needs access. Hope this helps

Comment: Check `APPPATH . 'config/rest.php'` file between lines 150-177. There is your answer.

Comment: @Tpojka.. There isnt such a code .. infact i checked rest.php entirely...
the only overriding method could only override username/pass auth

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
$config['auth_override_class_method']['products']['allproducts'] = 'none';
$config['auth_override_class_method']['devices']['updatedevice'] = 'basic';
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't override Key Authentication..

Only works with username/pass auth

Answer (score 0):

add the following code to "*application/config/rest.php*"

```
$config['auth_override_class_method']['Products']['allProducts'] = "none";
$config['auth_override_class_method']['Devices']['updateDevice'] = FALSE;
```

or you can just add this.

```
$config['auth_override_class_method']['Products']['allProducts'] = "none";
```

because your application automatically activates the token / is false so there is no need to add a route that activates the token again.